# What are the requirements for SQL Server taking transaction log backup in database set for Full Recovery Model?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have implemented Ola Hallengren's maintenance solution and transaction log backup is running every hour. I was going to perform restore test for one particular database today and noticed that although the database is in Full Recovery Mode there have been no transaction log backup taken. There were about 100 other databases running on this particular instance and about 95 of them had transaction log backups successfully taken.

I have just recently taken over this environment so I have no history as to how things have been set up or how these databases have been created.

When comparing the settings I against a database which was getting transaction log backup taken I see that the "Log Reuse Wait Description" is set to DATABASE_SNAPSHOT_CREATION for the database that does not have transaction log backup but LOG_BACKUP or NOTHING for those having successful transaction log backups taken.

I checked backup history and those that had transaction log backup today had history of successful backup last months but there was no history of any transaction log backup being taking for the databases that I am not seeing transaction log backup. I also checked and there are no long running transactions going on.

1. What should I check and how should I fix it so that the log backups start to generate for all the user databases?
2. And is there something I can do to prevent this from happening in future?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When was the last full backup on those five databases?  How many T-Log files for each of them?

Comment: Querying the backup history showed no last full backups in last 7 days so having a closer look revealed that those were indeed in offline, read only mode.

On the other hand I can confirm that the one I was trying to restore to a point in time did have daily full backups. I restored from last full backup, after the restore the database was in simple mode so I changed it to full recovery and transaction log backups started working. Before restore it was in Full Recovery Mode without getting transaction log backups. That is a fact and I don't understand how come.

Comment: It showed up in the following query and it certainly wasn't offline. 

SELECT d.name, 
       d.recovery_model, 
       d.recovery_model_desc 
FROM   master.sys.databases d 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset b 
                    ON d.name = b.database_name 
                       AND b.type = 'L' 
WHERE  d.recovery_model IN( 1, 2 ) 
       AND b.type IS NULL 
       AND d.database_id NOT IN( 2, 3 ); 
GO

Comment: The output from the DatabaseBackup stored procedure should give some more information about why a transaction log backup was not performed.

If you send me the output - file, I will have a look at it. You can find my contact information here. http://ola.hallengren.com/contact.html

Comment: Looking at the log files indicated that the database was indeed in SIMPLE recover mode. I confronted the personnel that brought the restore request to me and they had been trying to restore and apparently changed it to FULL recovery mode confusing things for me. Thank you for all for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

When you restored the last full backup, the database was in simple recovery mode.  Databases in simple recovery mode do not use transaction log backups.  In order to do transaction log backups you need:

1. Database in Full Recovery mode.
2. At least one full backup after switching to Full Recovery mode.

Comment: I am 100% sure that it was in Full recovery mode prior to the restore. It also came up as a result from the above query I posted. I know the database needs to be in full recovery mode to have transaction log backups. As I said, can it have anything to do with the DATABASE_SNAPSHOT_CREATION?

Comment: Yes - per Microsoft documentation, a log backup can't run while the log reuse wait is DATABASE_SHAPSHOT_CREATION.  You need to figure out why it is stuck in this status.  What happens when you run a full backup and a log backup right away?